# Is it possible to search for an transaction to or from an address with a time period filter?

Tags: blockchain, address

How can I search for a transaction to or from a certain address in the block chain within a particular time period?

I am trying to answer if this transaction occurred on 17 Oct 2014. Hence, instead of searching the entire block chain, it might be faster to search block chain, starting 16 Oct 2014 and ending on 18 Oct 2014.

Comment: Using what software?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to search transactions using time and volume with https://oxt.me/requester

Example: Alice saw some screenshot on social media which was posted between 9-9:15 PM UTC 1-2 March 2022 and involved sending 0.01 BTC

Volume in this case is sum of all outputs so this will return lot of results in some cases when more than one output is used. However you can always create your own software that will search based on amounts used in outputs for all transactions in a certain time period.

[image: oxt-requester]